# How can I display the actual value of a reference in C#

Tags: c#

I'm in the process of learning more about C# and am wondering how to display the actual value of a reference or the address of a struct.  I'm looking for is something analogous to the following C code:

```
    int i; 
    printf("int i resides at memory location %x",&i);
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What are you trying to learn? It's possible you can't learn it in this manner.

Comment: I'm trying to see how multi dimensional string arrays are stored on the heap. I'm an embedded guy and like to see where things go.

Comment: You might check out SOS for Windbg. Dump the process memory and look at where things are laid out. There are some discussions on .NET memory management as well. This list: http://geekswithblogs.net/sdorman/archive/2008/09/14/.net-memory-management-ndash-resources.aspx is fairly comprehensive.

Comment: Thanks GrayWizardx,  Actually I can get the info I want by using the C address operator on the objects in question in Visual Studio's watch window.  I was just curious if there was a way to do it in code. Inquiring minds want to know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In an `unsafe` context, this will work in C#:

```
int i = 10;
int *ptr = &i;
Console.WriteLine((int)ptr);
```

I don't know if it can be done in a safe context, or, if so, how (I suspect it can't).

Comment: In a non-trivial application would this be constant? I would assume that if this survived to gen 2 it might be constant, but before that it could move. I have never tried it though.

Comment: Section 18.3 of the C# spec explains this quite thoroughly. Look into the "fixed" statment. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21.aspx. It boils down to whether the pointer is looking at something that the GC considers movable or not.

Comment: The code as posted would show the content of the stack, not the GC heap.  Creating a pointer to a reference type requires pinning it first.  That's Heisbergian, you are now no longer are looking at the normal layout of the heap.  Use the sos.dll debugger extension, !dumpheap command.

Comment: Further to Gregory's answer, by default the GC will compact the heap after pruning dead objects to consolidate free space.  Therefore your objects can move around unless you mark them as pinned (which is usually only advisable if you need to exchange objects/pointers with unmananged code)

Answer (score 6):

This cannot be done in C#, that I am aware of. .NET takes the liberty of moving pieces of storage around as it sees fit, and so the address of a variable holds only temporary meaning at best.

Answer (score 0):

Although you *can* do this in some contexts, the result is largely meaningless. As has been noted, [References are not addresses](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/02/17/references-are-not-addresses.aspx) - or at least, they don't *have* to be. So what you are attempting, even if it works, isn't guaranteed over all implementations, and isn't usually particularly useful. If you don't pin, the value isn't reliable, and if you *do* pin you change the very thing you are reporting...

Really, you should be using different tools *outside* the language for this... windbg+SOS, for example.