# Reference types - can we see the actual reference?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, clr, il

The difference between reference types and value types is often confusing for beginners due to not understanding what a variable of value type actually holds.  We know that:

- Value types store the *actual* value
- Reference types only store the *reference* to the object

Is it possible to inspect each kind of variable to either see the value, or the **actual reference itself**?  Is the reference stored as some kind of coded value?  I know that references can be passed by value so I'm assuming so.

I think this would help newcomers with their understanding, and be very interesting to explore.

Comment: The only thing you would see is an address, a seemingly random number. Why would you want to see this?

Comment: To cement the idea that within the variable isn't the object they set, but rather an address.  How would we access this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978232/how-can-i-display-the-actual-value-of-a-reference-in-c-sharp

Comment: @m.edmonson,  confused at your question.  It's fundamental in .NET that an object's physical address is subject to change every time the GC does a mark and sweep.  It's an ephemeral quality in which developers have no interest.

Comment: The address is an [implementation detail](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx). It's important to understand the differences in behaviour rather than get to hung up on the implementation details. Just think of reference types as "somehow" pointing to a value rather than holding the value itself

Comment: Note that the address of an object on the heap can change over time when the GC relocates the object.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/02/17/references-are-not-addresses.aspx

Comment: @GarryVass This is not true for pinned objects, so the physical address of a pinned object sort of makes sense.

Comment: @EugenRieck, while I'm interested in knowing if an object is pinned, I'm doubtful that knowing its physical location will help me reclaim its memory.

Comment: It is also confusing for beginners when you conflate the declaration of a type with the declaration of a variable. "class C{}" is the declaration of a type. "C c;" is the declaration of a variable.  Similarly, it is confusing to say "value types store the value within the declaration". No. Value types do not store anything, and the declaration is a hunk of text in the source code editor. A *variable* of value type stores the value. It stores it in *the storage associated with the variable*.

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks for your input, I just got finished reading your blog post about references not being addresses, interesting read.  I've made your changes - let me know if it now reads accurately?

Comment: @Dykam, Garry Vass: My number one **pet hate** on StackOverflow is people saying "You shouldn't want to know that". Why would you want to **actively stifle** curiosity? Either answer the question or leave the OP alone!

Comment: @TomW, I totally support curiosity, however the right conclusions has to be taken from it. I've seen too often someone investigating a detail and concluding something totally irrelevant. His comment after that explained why he wanted to, that's why I asked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is it possible to inspect each kind of variable to either see the value, or the actual reference itself?

Just to clarify, the *value* of a *variable of reference type* **is** a reference. The reference is the value.

A reference is a kind of value, just like an int is a kind of value. Unlike an int, a reference is a value that can only be *copied* and *dereferenced*; you cannot observe its value directly in C#, because its value is an implementation detail of the garbage collector.

> Is the reference stored as some kind of coded value?

Yes, exactly. In practice, a reference is a 32 or 64 bit integer (depending on whether you are in a 32 or 64 bit process) that is a pointer to some structure known to the garbage collector as being associated with the data of the referred-to object.

If you want to look at references directly, the tool to do so is the debugger. Load your C# code into the debugger, compile it, run it, hit a breakpoint, and take a look at the state of the stack and registers. With a little cleverness you should be able to figure out which stack locations and registers correspond to which local variables. The locations corresponding to local variables of value type will contain the values; those of reference type will contain values that look like pointers. If you examine those pointers in the memory window, you will then be looking at the structures maintained by the garbage collector that describe the contents of the object.

Comment: I think it's important to note that while existing .net implementations may store addresses (of object-info records) in reference variables, there is no guarantee that future versions will do so.  It would be possible, for example, that some bits of a reference variable would be an index selecting one of a number of heaps, while other bits were an index within that heap.  While such a system might be inefficient with existing processors, designing future processors around such a model might allow more efficient cache utilization. Existing .net code shouldn't care about such details.

Comment: @supercat: Absolutely. In fact references could be implemented as entirely opaque handles that are only meaningful insofar as they index into some table owned by the garbage collector; there is no reason why *any* bit in a reference needs to have a particular meaning. As it happens, in today's implementations every bit of a reference *is* meaningful as it can be interpreted as a pointer. But that is subject to change at any time.

Comment: Out of curiosity, while existing CPU's probably wouldn't allow such things to be very efficient, I wonder whether it would be worthwhile in future CPUs to have a small-object heap for objects whose data is 8 (maybe 16) bytes or less, where each slot in object table would hold the actual object data instead of a pointer to it.  On existing CPUs, one would need extra instructions for each heap access to determine which heap any given reference belonged to, but if there were a "get object address" instruction which used a bit in the reference to select single or double indirection...

Comment: ...that would seem like it could greatly improve efficiency when accessing small objects.  Since I would guess that probably half of the object instances in a typical running program will be 16 bytes or less, if not 8, eliminating an extra memory fetch for each object access would seem like a big win.  Any idea if any new CPU's might support such a thing?

Comment: @supercat: Those are interesting musings. I know very little about hardware design; most of my interactions are with virtual machines. It would be interesting to put those questions to an expert in CPU architecture.

Answer (score 5):

This is probably one for Jon Skeet, but I might have a different angle on it:

**Don't worry** too much about *how* these things are represented in memory. Unless you have read through the whole language specification - who does that anyway? - you don't really need to know. Really. Don't bother memorizing what data is stored where - chances are, that this is implementation specific.

Instead, think in terms of semantics, e.g. that a value type passed to a function is *copied*, whereas a reference type is *referenced*. Stuff like that.

You don't really want to know what a declaration of a type actually holds. Believe me. What you want to know, is **how it behaves**.

Comment: +1 Here's where Eric Lippert [says](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/02/17/references-are-not-addresses.aspx) the same thing. The addresses are an implementation detail, the language specification does not mention addresses when specifying references. Learn how they behave and not how they work.

Comment: While I agree with your statement, I don't feel it's quite to the point of the question.  I think he'd like to know how to do it - not your opinions on why it's not important.  Leaning how complex functionality works can make you a better engineer even if you don't find an instant use for that knowledge.

Comment: Whilst I both thank and agree with your answer it doesn't address the point of my question.  I'd merely like to access the address **just to prove it's there** no other reason.  I agree with @AdamG.Carstensen.

Comment: @AdamG.Carstensen - I agree with both of you: I didn't really answer your question. But you do mention "helping newcomers understand" as a reason and I think it doesn't really help newcomers much. But it would be interesting to view this from a VM implementation perspective.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a pinned object quite easily;

```
GCHandle gch=GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr AddressInMemory=gch.AddrOfPinnedObject();
```

Comment: This won't work for [non-blittable types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7.aspx), like almost all classes.

Comment: I stand corrected. Looks like the only time I ever needed this was with primitives.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `unsafe` code:

```
    unsafe
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "Hello";

        fixed (char* pc = s)
        {                
            IntPtr p = (IntPtr)pc;
            Console.WriteLine(p);   // here is your meaningless address 
        }            
    }
```

Comment: This makes a pinned copy of s, so you why not pin s directly?

Comment: We're not going to use `s` for anything.

Comment: @EugenRieck Do you have a source for that statement? I see no copying here.